# Launching pyscipopt Mac

Tags: python, macos, scip

I am trying to use pyscipopt on a Mac. I downloaded the SCIP Optimization Suite in my application folder, then gave the directory "`export SCIPOPTDIR=/Applications`" in the terminal and finally gave the directory pip install pyscipopt in the terminal.

When I try to `import pyscipopt using Anaconda`, I have the following error message :

---

```
from pyscipopt import *
```

> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/**init**.py", line 5, in 
>       from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
>
> ImportError: dlopen(/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libscip.4.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/scip.cpython-36m-darwin.so

**Reason: image not found**

---

I went in the folder `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyscipopt/` and tried to opened the file `scip.cpython-36m-darwin`.so but the same error appeared.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you in advance,
Kind regards,

Thibault Martinelle

Comment: Your `SCIPOPTDIR` variable is not specific enough. According to the [Install instructions](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst), you must specify the directory that contains "lib" and "include" of the scipoptsuite, which probably reside in /Applications/scipoptsuite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't have the directory /Applications/SCIPOptSuite because when I download the file, I have only the possibility to drag 3 files : bin, lib, include in the file Applications. Then I only have those three files in my folder Applications and not a scipoptsuite file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It is important to use the most recent version (>= 5.0) of the SCIP Optimization Suite, libraries from the older archives are no longer compatible.

Comment: I tried the version 5.0 as well and I have the same problem. With the version 5.1 they say that it is impossible to open the image of the disc when I try to open the file after agreeing the Terms and Conditions.

Comment: Sorry for your troubles. Instead of downloading the .dmg package, you can also download the scipoptsuite-5.0.1 sources and try to build it following these [instructions](http://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/CMAKE.php)

Comment: The applications directory is irrelevant here. You need to extract the three directories (bin, lib, include) to some directory on your system. This is the SCIPOPTDIR that you need to specify for PySCIPOpt.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [installation instructions on Github](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst). You did not specify the correct `SCIPOPTDIR`. It's not the directory where the SCIP Opt Suite directory is located but instead this directory itself, i.e. `/Applications/SCIPOptSuite 5.0.1`.

It also does not look like you're using the latest versions of neither [PySCIPOpt](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt) nor the [SCIP Opt Suite](http://scip.zib.de/#download).

edit:

You might need to add the directory where the `libscip.dylib` is located to your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` if it cannot be found during runtime and there were no errors when calling `pip install pyscipopt`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't have the directory /Applications/SCIPOptSuite because when I download the file, I have only the possibility to drag 3 files : bin, lib, include in the file Applications. Then I only have those three files in my folder Applications and not a scipoptsuite file.

Thank you for your help!